# How to add a php file link in menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I am the begineer in WP trying to convert my HTML site to Wordpress theme. Everything working fine but i want to link one page having name contact-us.php in my theme root directory , i want to link this page with contact us menu in the header.

Comment: why you want to use the same file as you are using wordpress you can easily use pre build plugins for this purpose. There are many plugins are available for free in wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing things is not recommended.
When you want to create a contact-us page create a template in Wordpress
[Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)

In the backoffice you can create a new page and select this template in the sidebar on the right

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make a template to your contact us file.
Use this code on the top of contact us file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Contact Us Page
 */
?>
```

And make a page from its backend and select contact us page template from the rightside. After that create a menu from menu section. I hope it will be work.